# Scala plugin for IntelliJ Idea: different editions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea Ultimate edition there is [Play framework support](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/play_framework.html)  provided by Scala plugin.

The same Scala plugin is also available in Community edition, but you don't get Play framework support there.

Is it just an artificial restriction in [Scala plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala) (which is open-source), or does it depend on some functionality provided by Ultimate edition only?

Comment: [Comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) states that Play support is only available in Ultimate edition.

Comment: Bohuslav Burghardt - yes, that's what I wrote in my question. Please read it again.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that it is only available in Ultimate editition, as is the case with most framework plugins. Whether that is artificial restriction or architectural dependency on some Ultimate components only someone from Jetbrains can probably answer. If I had to take a guess I'd say it is the artifical to make people upgrade to Ultimate ... Either way good luck, hope you find the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play support requires parts from IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition sources, so there is no way to make it available in Community edition (you can hack Scala plugin and enable Play support in Community edition, but you will get lots of ClassNotFound exceptions). Besides this it's main idea of differences between Community and Ultimate edition. Ultimate edition contains web-related parts.